# google finance function not correct in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

The function below should be pulling back the amazon share price on 04/04/2020. The result states $11.43 which is incorrect. This has been working for the past 6 months but not today for some reason. Is this an issue with google finance ?

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("amzn","price",date(2020,4,4))
```

Result is:

```
Date                    Close
06/04/2020 16:00:00     11.43
```

Comment: whats the correct value and why?

Comment: problem found - look at this https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+share+price&oq=amazon+share&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i57j0l5j69i61.3583j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

well 04/04/2020 is Saturday so

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("amzn", "price", DATE(2020, 4, 4))
```

will round it up to Monday 6th

[image]

if you want to get the latest value **11,2** (from Friday 04/03/2020) you can do:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AMZN", "price", 
 IF(TEXT(DATE(2020, 4, 4), "ddd")="Sat", DATE(2020, 4, 4)-1, 
 IF(TEXT(DATE(2020, 4, 4), "ddd")="Sun", DATE(2020, 4, 4)-2, 
 DATE(2020, 4, 4))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi - thanks for response. the issue is the result there in your image showing 11.20 dollars. Run your query aghain and you'll see the price is different. there must of been an issue with google for that day where the numbers got messed up server side....